# Organize directory b and its subdirectories files equal as directory a without copying or moving from directory a

Tags: files, move

I'm looking for some way to organize the files contained in directory `b` to make its structure equal to that of directory `a` (which contains the same files as `b`, just arranged in a different way), without copying or moving anything from directory `a`. That way seek some advanced use of `mv` command with output from `awk` or/and `sed` commands, as following images.

Model directories before as `Errors a` and it without modifications, as `Errors b`:

```
.                                       .
└── Errors a                            └── Errors b
    ├── Eltendorf                           ├── Eltendorf
    │   ├── 2013 March 09.txt               │   ├── 2013 March 09.txt
    │   ├── 2014 November 07.txt            │   ├── 2014 November 07.txt
    │   ├── 2016 August 03.txt              │   ├── 2016 August 03.txt
    │   └── 2017 October 02.txt             │   └── 2017 October 02.txt
    ├── Gettendorf                          ├── Gettendorf
    │   ├── 2011 August 05.txt              │   ├── 2011 August 05.txt
    │   ├── 2014 October 02.txt             │   ├── 2014 October 02.txt
    │   ├── 2014 October 09.txt             │   ├── 2014 October 09.txt
    │   └── 2015 November 08.txt            │   └── 2015 November 08.txt
    ├── Krensdorf                           ├── Krensdorf
    │   ├── 2010 August 04.txt              │   ├── 2010 August 04.txt
    │   ├── 2010 November 04.txt            │   ├── 2010 November 04.txt
    │   └── 2012 August 09.txt              │   └── 2012 August 09.txt
    └── Ritzing                             └── Ritzing
        ├── 2013 March 01.txt                   ├── 2013 March 01.txt
        ├── 2013 March 02.txt                   ├── 2013 March 02.txt
        ├── 2013 March 03.txt                   ├── 2013 March 03.txt
        └── 2018 November 02.txt                └── 2018 November 02.txt
```

Contents directories `Errors c` before, and after, as desired, as `Errors d`:

```
.                                       .
└── Errors c                            └── Errors d
    ├── Eltendorf                           ├── Eltendorf
    │   ├── 2010 November 04.txt            │   ├── 2013 March 09.txt
    │   ├── 2013 March 02.txt               │   ├── 2014 November 07.txt
    │   ├── 2014 November 07.txt            │   ├── 2016 August 03.txt
    │   └── 2014 October 09.txt             │   └── 2017 October 02.txt
    ├── Gettendorf                          ├── Gettendorf
    │   ├── 2012 August 09.txt              │   ├── 2011 August 05.txt
    │   ├── 2013 March 03.txt               │   ├── 2014 October 02.txt
    │   ├── 2014 October 02.txt             │   ├── 2014 October 09.txt
    │   └── 2017 October 02.txt             │   └── 2015 November 08.txt
    ├── Krensdorf                           ├── Krensdorf
    │   ├── 2010 August 04.txt              │   ├── 2010 August 04.txt
    │   ├── 2013 March 01.txt               │   ├── 2010 November 04.txt
    │   ├── 2015 November 08.txt            │   └── 2012 August 09.txt
    │   └── 2018 November 02.txt            └── Ritzing
    └── Ritzing                                 ├── 2013 March 01.txt
        ├── 2011 August 05.txt                  ├── 2013 March 02.txt
        ├── 2013 March 09.txt                   ├── 2013 March 03.txt
        └── 2016 August 03.txt                  └── 2018 November 02.txt
```

That way directory `c` should become equal to directory `a` without copying directory `a` contents.

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework?

Comment: No, it's a backup procedure.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead for example input

Comment: I edited your post because some important information wasn't visible (the images' alt text). Please, check if this helps conveying the desired meaning. Can you confirm that you have a directory `Error c` which already contains the same files that are in `Error a` and which you want to rearrange so that it becomes the shown `Error d` (which, in turn, is the same as `Error a`)? This is how I read your question, but it wasn't immediately clear to me.

Comment: Just adjusted as requested, @muru.

Comment: Yes, that can be confirmed, @fra-san. It's a backup of some data, as there is an organized directory structure and is desired to organize another structure with equal content.

Comment: I think this can be done with just `mkdir "Errors b"; cp -a "Errors a"/. "Errors b"` and similarly for c and d.

Comment: `Errors a` and `Errors b` are just models of before and after the command. Files permutations should be just on `Errors c`, to become `Errors d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, for simplicity, that your original data is in directory `a`:

```
a
├── d1
│   ├── f1
│   └── f2
└── d2
    ├── f3
    └── f4
```

and that you have a directory `b` which contains the same files as `a`, organized as a different directory structure:

```
b
├── d1
│   └── f3
├── d2
│   ├── f1
│   └── f2
└── d3
    └── f4
```

To rearrange the files in `b` to match `a`'s hierarchy without copying anything from `a` to `b`:

```sh
export orig=a dest=b
find "$orig" -type f -exec sh -c '
    for file; do
        target=$dest${file#$orig}
        target=${target%/*}
        mkdir -p -- "$target"
        find "$dest" -type f -name "${file##*/}" \
            -exec mv -i -- \{\} "$target/" \;
    done
    ' mysh {} +
```

This not-really-efficient code (it spawns a new `find` process for every file in `a`):

- searches for every regular file in `a`,
- defines a target directory as the file's parent directory with `a` replaced by `b`,
- creates the target directory (`makedir -p` doesn't complain about already existing directories and also creates all the needed parents),
- searches for every file in `b` named as the current one and moves them to the target directory; `mv -i` asks before overwriting, to avoid losing data if two files in distinct subdirectories of `b` happened to have the same name.

You may then want to remove regular files or directories in `b` (such as `d3` in our example) which are not in `a`:

```sh
export orig=a dest=b
find "$dest" \( -type f -o -type d \) -exec sh -c '
    target=$orig${1#$dest}
    [ ! -e "$target" ]
    ' mysh {} \; -delete
```

The final result is:

```
b
├── d1
│   ├── f1
│   └── f2
└── d2
    ├── f3
    └── f4
```

Answer (score 2):

find, sed, xargs, mkdir:

```
find a -type d|sed '1d;s/a\///'|xargs -i mkdir -p c/{}
```

Comment: This command only created the directories, didn't moved the files as `Errors a` sort.

Comment: @Ronald71 This is what you _explicitly_ asked about: "without copying directory a contents."